# Confirmation email with token From Rails API + React app. Where to redirect if it's an api?

Tags: reactjs, rails-api

I have two separate apps, a Rails only API and a react App. I am trying to authenticate the user with a link in an email (which has a token).

What I have so far is:

1 In the React App, user presses a `login with fb` button, which logs in with fb. 
2 With the fb response, I send a request to Rails API and I save the user in the Rails API database. 
3 In the Rails API, after that, I send an email to the user so that he can click a link with the token
4 User clicks the link in the email and Rails API receives this request with the token, and activates user in the database.

Now comes my question. Since it's an api, I can not respond with an html page saying, now you are authenticated, please login again or sth.

What should I do?
1) Is there a way from an API to send the user to a react URL? I mean, that the user goes to a page of my React App
2) Should the Rails API generate the link with token, but based on the React domain, and once the user clicks the link in the email, somehow go to the react app, and not to the rails api, and then from the react app, send the request to the rails api with this token? this way, when Rails Api response, I can navigate with React to another page because I am in the React app

The confirmation of the email looks like this:

```
  resources :users, only: [] do
    member do
      get :confirm_email
    end
  end
```

and the action does this at some point, after having found the user:

```
  def email_activate
    self.email_confirmed = true
    self.confirm_token = nil
    save!(:validate => false)
  end
```

And the link in the email looks like this:

```
<%= confirm_email_user_url(@user.confirm_token) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of rails but here's a generic answer.

I would create a UI for your activation page in your react app. The url could be as follows: `myreactapp.com/activate?token=<insert_activation_token_here>`.

This path will serve a nice UI. Either on the front-end or back-end of this path (whichever more convenient), you can communicate with your API and pass on the token. The url could be as follows: `myapi.com/activate?token=<token_from_react>`.

This page could show a success or failure screen or whatever you like after receiving a response from the API.

---

Edit: This seems like a more architectural and subjective question so there's probably a wide variety of solutions.

Comment: yes, this is actually my second option. From the email, when user clicks the token-link, I transfer this token to the react app, and there I can do whatever you want as you said. Thanks a lot for your time